Carousel autoscroll is not working when it focus jetpack compose
I am facing an issue regarding Carousel. Here I share my code. In this code I want to perform autoscroll my images.
When I am focusing any of other view around carousel that time autoscroll will properly as expect working but when I move focus on carousel that time autoscrolling will stop. And again move focus on any other view so again working fine.
I want to autoscrolling my all images without stop the autoscrolling features where the focus I don't care about just autoscroll needed.
What can I try next?
My code
@ExperimentalTvMaterial3Api
@Composable
fun HeroBanner(
    focusRequesters: MutableMap<Pair<String, Int>, FocusRequester>,
    categoryItem: HomeLayout.CategoryItem,
    cateItems: List<HomeLayout.CategoryItem.Item>?,
    onFocusChange: (focusState: FocusState, pos: Int) -> Unit,
    goToVideoPlayer: (pos: Int, item: HomeLayout.CategoryItem.Item) -> Unit,
) {
    val carouselHeight = LocalConfiguration.current.screenHeightDp.dp.times(0.60f)
    var carouselCurrentIndex by rememberSaveable { mutableIntStateOf(0) }
    val carouselState = rememberCarouselState()
    var isCarouselFocused by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    LaunchedEffect(carouselState.activeItemIndex) {
        carouselCurrentIndex = carouselState.activeItemIndex
    }
    val fr = remember { FocusRequester() }
    focusRequesters[Pair(categoryItem.id, 0)] = fr
    if (cateItems != null) {
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(20.dp))
        cateItems.sortedBy { it.priority }
        AnimatedContent(targetState = cateItems,
            label = "Featured Carousel animation",
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .height(carouselHeight)
                .padding(start = 20.dp, end = 20.dp)
                .focusRequester(fr)
                .onFocusChanged {
                    onFocusChange(it, 0)
                    // Because the carousel itself never gets the focus
                    isCarouselFocused = it.hasFocus
                }) { itemState ->
            Carousel(modifier = Modifier
                .onFocusChanged {
                    Log.e("TAG", "HeroBanner: focus ${it.isFocused}")
//                    onFocusChange(it, 0)
                }
                .fillMaxSize()
                .semantics {
                    contentDescription = "MoviesCarousel"
                }
                .handleDPadKeyEvents(onEnter = {
                    goToVideoPlayer(
                        carouselState.activeItemIndex,
                        cateItems[carouselState.activeItemIndex]
                    )
                }),
                itemCount = itemState.size,
                carouselState = carouselState,
                carouselIndicator = {
                    Box(modifier = Modifier
                        .padding(10.dp)
                        .graphicsLayer {
                            clip = true
                            shape = ShapeDefaults.ExtraSmall
                        }
                        .align(Alignment.BottomEnd)) {
                        CarouselDefaults.IndicatorRow(
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .align(Alignment.BottomEnd)
                                .padding(8.dp),
                            itemCount = itemState.size,
                            activeItemIndex = carouselState.activeItemIndex,
                        )
                    }
                },
                contentTransformStartToEnd = CarouselDefaults.contentTransform,
                contentTransformEndToStart = CarouselDefaults.contentTransform,
                autoScrollDurationMillis = 5000,
                content = { index ->
                    val item = remember(index) { itemState[index] }
                    HeroBannerContent(item = item, categoryItem = categoryItem) {
                        goToVideoPlayer(carouselState.activeItemIndex, item)
                    }
                })
        }
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(10.dp))
    }
}

Here when Log : HeroBanner: focus false
That time autoscroll will working fine.
but when i move focus on Carousel then
Log : HeroBanner: focus true
So now autoscrolling will stop.
My requirement is autoscroll continues even carousel is focused or not.
Note : This code is for Android Tv app.

In the beta release of tv-material, the some of the carousel features were dropped due to technical limitations. Source

@vighnesh153
I am using this library in my app.
api("androidx.compose.material3:material3-android:1.2.1")   api("androidx.tv:tv-material:1.0.0-beta01")
So can i managed in this or wait for new update?

The Carousel bugs will be fixed in androidx.tv:tv-material:1.1.0-alpha01. You can use the other components from androidx.tv:tv-material as they have no known bugs.

@vighnesh153
I can't resolve 'androidx.tv:tv-material:1.1.0-alpha01'
instead i tried 'androidx.tv:tv-material:1.0.0-alpha10' this but still not solve my problem.
and I think 'androidx.tv:tv-material:1.0.0-beta01' is latest one.
Can you explain more about it. If i am something missing.
I am referring [Material Link] (https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/tv#kts) this link.
and there is not available version you mention 1.1.0-alpha01.

The 1.1.0-alpha01 version is not yet released.

So for now any other way to manage autoscroll carousel even focus or not focus carousel ?
I you have please explain me or give me some example. @vighnesh153

You can copy the Carousel code from the library and uncomment the commented bits: https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:tv/tv-material/src/main/java/androidx/tv/material3/Carousel.kt
